# Printing linux man-help like on python

Tags: python, formatting, message

I am trying to build a help message output for my custom app like Linux man does. I've been walking around pprint, using dictionaries, and others. But, I'm al little lost. I'm currently using a dictionary combined with print commands. Until now is enough for my needs but I must confess It's not up to scratch.

I would like to use the flags command style, I mean, -f , -t , etc. I supose that the point of establish is to extract data using a parser o something like that.

So, in a few words, How do you guys build help messages for the properly usage of your command based apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) and [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) both support printing usage details.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank's a lot. You've made me save a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

There's the [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) module, and its successor [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) (the first one is deprecated since Python 2.7). These modules automatically generate help output like this one (from the Python docs):

```
$ prog.py -h
usage: prog.py [-h] [--sum] N [N ...]

Process some integers.

positional arguments:
 N           an integer for the accumulator

optional arguments:
 -h, --help  show this help message and exit
 --sum       sum the integers (default: find the max)
```